# Deletion not removing the ID in solr document

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

If we remove a row in datastax cassandra, DataStax will remove all fields in solr, but leave its ID(uniqueKey) field. This uniqueKey field getting indexed in solr search with no data for all other fields. How to remove this uniqueKey value in solr?

Example search results(First document having only uniqueKey value but this record is deleted in database):

```
 {
        "groupValue":"b00naxzgps",
      "doclist":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
          {
            "_uniqueKey":"[\"B00NAXZGPS\",\"1439337600000\",\"5790.0\",\"Amazon\"]"}]
      }},
    {
      "groupValue":"acce3f2aybn5yyht",
      "doclist":{"numFound":9,"start":0,"docs":[
          {
            "_uniqueKey":"[\"ACCE3F2AYBN5YYHT\",\"1439942400000\",\"349.0\",\"Flipkart\"]",
            "product_id":"ACCE3F2AYBN5YYHT",
            "location":"null",
            "product_name":"Airnet USB for ZTE Blade G2 Car Charger",
            "state":"null",
            "address1":"null",
            "address2":"null",
            "updated_time":"2015-08-19T17:47:28.876Z",
            "product_group":"mobile_accessories",
            "city":"null",
            "updated_date":"2015-08-19T00:00:00Z",
            "longitude":0.0,
            "user_id":"null",
            "imageurl":"null",
            "currency_code":"INR",
            "mrp_price":699.0}]
      }},
```

Comment: What's your "autoSoftCommit" time? I've seen this when the index delete just hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: Also, what is your DSE version?

Comment: @CalebRackliffe "autoSoftCommit" time is 10000 milliseconds.

Comment: @sbtourist My DSE version is 4.7.1

Comment: @asr If the document still isn't gone after those 10 seconds, I'd be interested to see your schema.xml. If the elements of the Solr unique key/Cassandra primary key are not indexed, deletes will not work properly.

Comment: @CalebRackliffe Attaching schema.xml

Comment: <fields>
<field indexed="true"  name="product_id" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="product_name" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="source" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="updated_date" stored="true" type="DateField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="sale_price" stored="true" type="DoubleField"/>
</fields>
 <defaultSearchField>product_name</defaultSearchField>
<uniqueKey>(product_id,updated_date,sale_price,source)</uniqueKey>

Comment: @asr It is typically not a good idea to use an analyzed field, like "TextField" in your unique key. (See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#Text_field_in_the_document.) If you use "StrField", and deletes still aren't registering after commit, then we'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: @CalebRackliffe Its worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!!.

Comment: @CalebRackliffe After couple of days we are getting same issue. We didn't made any changes. The unique key field type is strField only.

Comment: @asr Interesting. At this point, I'm going to recommend that you upgrade to 4.7.3. There were a few things around this in 4.7.1 that may be causing you trouble. If that still doesn't work, we probably need to take a fresh look at the CQL and Solr schemas.